# Dispatcher Problems in visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use the [Dispatcher.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) method in the [System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) class. IntelliSense as well as the documentation shows that there are 9 overloads of this method, but IntelliSense gives you only 4 of those options to implement, though i can implement the ones that don't show up in the overloads list. What's wrong and how to fix that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some mebmers are marked with

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

and will never be shown by intellisense.

Other members are marked with

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
```

and to show them use Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | Statement completion | Hide advanced members

More details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx).

Comment: I see. do you have any idea why such an important method which enables you to modify controls on the UI thread be hidden from the designer ?

Comment: No idea :( But you don't even have to use this method. You can just check Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread instead.